# What is this hard old Spanish manuscript about?

Tags: escritura-manuscrita

I could not understand this manuscript.

Does it say "moorish Mohammed"? What is the context?

[image: Compendio de crónicas de reyes del Antiguo Testamento, gentiles, cónsules y emperadores romanos, reyes godos y de los reinos de Castilla, Aragón, Navarra y Portugal]

[Original link](http://bdh-rd.bne.es/viewer.vm?lang=es&id=0000051546&page=59&fbclid=IwAR1unagCFidH9pxJozU-NhP1LDH1GxaZRezqHPmQK4cwNjHEZGXVzKvNvBI)

Comment: What is your exact question? No one would say in English: Moorish Mohammed or in Spanish, either. Where do you think that is in the visible text??

Comment: It is not scripture; it is a manuscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La información al respecto que aparece es la siguiente;

"
Título: Compendio de crónicas de reyes del Antiguo Testamento, gentiles, cónsules y emperadores romanos, reyes godos y de los reinos de Castilla, Aragón, Navarra y Portugal [Manuscrito].Inc.: Commo sea summa prudencia a todos los entendidos aver en memoria (h. 1r) ... Exp.: Este fue muy buen rey e muy justiçiero e mantovo muy bien su tierra en paz & con muy gran justicia. Deo gracias (h. 44v)

Fecha entre 1301 y 1400?

Tipo de Documento Manuscrito

Materia Historia antigua - Obras ilustradas
España - Reyes y soberanos
Portugal - Reyes y soberanos
Manuscritos iluminados

Descripción física44 h. (2 col) : perg.; 30 x 21 cm

Signatura MSS/7415

PID bdh0000051546

Resumen: Termina en Castilla con Alfonso XI siendo niño, y en Portugal con D. Dionís

Descripción y notas Domínguez Bordona, Mss. con pinturas, I p. 277, n. 608.
PhiloBiblon, BETA manid 4713
Rodríguez Porto, Rosa María, Thesaurum : la Crónica troyana de Alfonso XI (Escorial, H.I.6) y los libros iluminados de la monarquía castellana (1284 -1369) : tesis doctoral ; dirigida por Rocío Sánchez Ameijeiras. Universidade Santiago de Compostela, Facultad de Geografía e Historia, Departamento de Historia da Arte, septiembre 2012 t. II, pp. 215 -260.

Letra gótica textual irregular

Inicial miniada. Escudo de armas en h. 2, en oro y colores. Dos toscas figuras en cada página, dibujadas e iluminadas, que representan monarcas antiguos y de los reinos peninsulares"

---

Estos son documentos ó "Cronicones", donde no siempre la información que aparece es veraz y por tanto siempre es bueno contrastarla con otros datos y Códices.

Este tipo de "Compendio de crónicas de reyes del Antiguos" son pequeñas historias, aclaraciones ó aspectos relacionados con la vida de algunos Reyes y personajes.

No he leído nada que diga "Mahoma moro", ni nada por el estilo.

**Contexto:**

En el documento hay dos figuras.

- Por una parte aparece *Mahoma*, imagino que serán con las enseñanzas del Corán en la mano. En este apartado se habla a groso modo de los hechos que ocurrieron en tiempos de los godos narrando la vida de Mahoma, cuando predico, los males de sus enseñanzas, a la edad que falleció (según el texto) y los años que hace desde la Pasión de Jesús hasta el nacimiento de la nueva religión.
- Por otra parte se encuentra sentado *Atanarico*, con la espada y el orbe en cada una de las manos. Considerado por los visigodos como su rey fundador. En este apartado, cuenta como los Visigodos, grandes señores, vinieron también de Oriente, de allá del Danubio, su larga travesía hasta llegar a España y el primer Rey Visigodo considerado por ellos, aunque este dato, según desde el punto que se mire puede ser erróneo.
  En la página abajo a la derecha hay unas fechas escritas y al lado pone que están erradas (herradas), imagino que están referidas a Atanagildo, pero quizás el texto del documento alude a Atanarico, aunque para la historiografía Española el primer Rey Visigodo oficialmente es Ataúlfo (372-415), hijo precisamente de Atanarico ó Athanarico (318-381).

---

El Español antiguo esta adaptado, traduzco solo el primer párrafo, que comienza por la letra azul, que parece ser que es el que más interesado estas;

- En el tiempo que los godos

pasaron la mar se murió Mahoma

de Medina y fue a tierras de Arabia y

comenzó a predicar su ley y convirtió

a muchas gentes y les dio por Ley

muchas malas cosas y muy sucias

y hará cuarenta años cuando comenzó

a predicar. Y se llamaba mensajero

de Dios. De esto fue en la Era de

Seiscientos sesenta y dos años de

que Nuestro Señor Jesucristo tomo pa-

sión, hasta que Mahoma comenzó

a predicar su ley. Y vivió Mahoma

sesenta y cuatro años.

P.D. Las fechas y datos numéricos son siempre cuestionables. Saludos

Comment: Qué título? No entiendo nada del contenido de tu respuesta en relación al texto que cita el OP.

Comment: Eso es solo información de documento, Titulo, Fecha, Materia.... Lo importante se encuentra a partir de la palabra "Contexto" y la traducción del primer párrafo la tienes más abajo.

Comment: A mi me gustaria saber mas del texto. Para poder leerlo. Lo demas no me importa tanto...:)

Comment: Lo tienes debajo; En el tiempo que los godos
pasaron la mar se murió Mahoma

de Medina y fue a tierras de Arabia y

comenzó a predicar su ley y convirtió

a muchas gentes y les dio por Ley

Comment: Pues, Diego, dile eso claramente. El quiso saber lo del "moorish Mohammed" que no se encuentra el texto ¿ verdad? Es: Mahoma de Medina. Mohammed of Medina. :) No creo que entienda el castellano. :)

Comment: !Si, Mahoma de Medina!    -             In the time that the Goths
They crossed the sea, Muhammad died

from Medina and went into the lands of Arabia and

he began to preach the law of it and converted

to many people and he gave them by Law

many bad things and very dirty

and he will be forty years old when he began

to preach And he was called messenger

of God. Of this was in the Age of

Six hundred and sixty-two years of

that Our Lord Jesus Christ took pa-

sion, until Muhammad began

to preach his law. And Muhammad lived

sixty-four years.

Comment: At time the Goths crossed the sea,  Muhammed of Medina died and went into the lands of Arabia and began to preach his law and converted many people and he gave them by Law many bad and very dirty things and he will be forty years old when he began to preach.  And he was called **himself** messenger of God. The text is full of odd verb tenses.

Comment: OK - He was the messenger of God
He called himself the messenger of God
He said that he was the messenger of God.

Comment: - The text is full of odd verb tenses - I have written it using modern Spanish, but adapting it so that you can follow almost word by word each line of the paragraph. Thinking it could also be an academic question. Although in ancient times the passive form was widely used.

Comment: Yes, called himself. :) Boy, those Christians were so rabidly anti-Muslim.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Comment: Creo que pone "se movió" y no "se murió". Tiene más sentido además. Muy completa la respuesta por cierto. :-)